# Windows PC does not have full download speed

Tags: windows, networking, download, internet-speed

I have a Windows computer on my network that is not downloading with max speed ( 1GBit/s / 125MByte/s ).

On every test I run (several online tools, downloading games, etc.), the maximum reached is about 11-12MBytes/s with let me think that some software is capping the maximum speed at 100MBit/s.

I'm almost certain that this issue is software-related. Other machines in this network connected to the same router getting about 115-120 MByte/s.
I connected a MacBook to the same cable (CAT 6 SF/UTP) and it's receiving the same high speed as the other machines, so it must be a problem with windows.

### Some additional information

- Win 10 Home 64 Bit
- Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
- Only connected via LAN. No hops between router and computer.

### What I tried

- Updating the driver
- Using a tool called TCP Optimizer. Worked first, but the Windows update resetted the network settings. Using the tool again changed nothing
- Changed network speed manually in adapter settings from automatic -> 1GBit/s Full Duplex. This resulted in the network adapter not working at all. It says I have to plug in a cable ???

Comment: It sounds to me more like you might have a cable issue. If forcing 1Gb/FD fails then it suggests that the cable cannot support it or that the connector in your network card is damaged

Comment: Have you asked your ISP?  Best starting point. Are you reaching a cap in download volume that limits your speed?

Comment: What is the router? Try perhaps to factory reset it.

Comment: @widepeepohappy: **1)** If it's worked after using tool called `TCP Optimizer` than try to use this tool the second time? **2)** And if you open the Ethernet connection status what `Speed` do you see `1Gbps` or `100Mbps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply switched cables. Everything works fine now.